# How to access index.php on my live demo themes

Tags: html, .htaccess

I want to access the following URL: https://invitera.id/themes/1/index.php

However with my current .htaccess configuration, I am receiving a HTTP 500 response.

My `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.invitera.id
RewriteRule (.*) https://invitera.id/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm index2.html
```

Comment: Too many redirect issue? What does /var/log/apache2/error.log (or similar) say?

Comment: PHP Warning:  include(../koneksi.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/inva8299/public_html/themes/1/index.php on line 1

Comment: Looks like that may be the issue.